# Backbone.js Singleton Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm building an application with Backbone.js and require.js. My collections get the data from the backend via the fetch() function. Now I have a case where the fetch function is expensive and the data for this specific collection won't change and I'll have such more collections. So I want to keep the data/collection in the memory. But I'm struggling by the implementation. I want to keep the lazy loading given by require.js. What are usual and "clean" ways to handle that?

Comment: i think you can override fetch metod - for example you can check if model inctance have cached results (lets call in cachedData) return in, else make default fetch action and store results in cachedData.

Comment: can explain why the fetch is expensive? I mean, you don't have to call it...

Comment: @MildFuzz fetch the data from the backend. This is kind of static data which has to be fetched only once. So I have to call fetch() but only one time.

Comment: @Evgeniy I don't use the same instance. So I cannot store this on the instance itself.

Comment: well, that's fine, only call it once. Done....

Comment: @Mild Fuzz Well, that is what I want, but the question is/was how to handle that and was answered by David Sulc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript closures, something like:

```
var getCollection = (function(){
  var coll;

  return function(){
    if( ! coll){
      coll = new MyCollection();
      coll.fetch();
    }
    return coll;
  }
}());
```

The first time you call `getCollection`, the collection will be fetched. Then, each subsequent call will get the cached value.

For more on these kinds of patterns, take a look at "Javascript patterns" by Stoyan Stafanov (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do)

Comment: Ok, just implement the Singleton pattern. :) At the moment I asked the question I should thought about that. :D

Comment: No, not simple the Singleton pattern. Can you explain why it works with the closure? Or shall I use Google? :)

Comment: For a detailed answer you'll need Google, or the linked book. Essentially, the `coll` variable is accessible within the closure of the function that gets created and assigned to `getCollection`. So you can use `coll` to store the singleton value and return it if it's defined.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But one more thing came me in mind. Usually I would do it like ‘window.collection.foo = new FooCollection()‘ inside the collection instead of using the closure. Are there advantages/disadvantages for each of them?

Comment: The problem is that you'll never know if `window.collection.foo` is initialized or not. So you'll bascially be doing that checking everywhere in your code. Instead you should assign the code in my answer as `window.collection.getFoo`.